# Extensions of finite groups by compact Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Let $K$ and $Q$ be discrete groups, with $K$ abelian. Central extensions of $Q$ by $K$, i.e. short exact sequences $1 \to K \to G \to Q \to 1$ such that $K$ is lies in the center of $G$, are classified (up to equivalence) by $H^2(Q;K)$, where $K$ is a trivial $Q$-module. There are also corresponding versions of this statement for (a) non-central extensions, and (b) $K$ not necessarily abelian.

My question is whether there exists a way of classifying compact Lie groups which arise as extensions of $Q$ by $K$ when $K$ is assumed to be a compact and connected Lie group. I would be happy to know what happens even in special cases, e.g. when $K$ is circle.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a central extension $1\rightarrow S^1\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ where $Q$ is compact and suppose that you have local continuous sections, you can find a cover $(U_i)$ of $Q$ with sections $s_i:U_i\rightarrow G$, $s_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow S^1$ defined by $s_{ij}=s_is_j^{-1}$ is a Cech cocycle defined on $G$ which takes it values in $S^1$, you have a classifying cocycle $s$ defined by $s_{ij}$ whose class $[s]\in H^1(Q,S^1)=H^2(Q,\mathbb{Z})$ in fact it is the Chern class of a complex line bundle defined on $Q$.

Comment: Notice the question wants $Q$ discrete.

Comment: The answer is exactly the same even if $K$ is not discrete.

Comment: But that special case is certainly special. For example, there are not a lot of complex line bundles on $Q$… so your Chern  class is not very interesting! (You should notice that the $H^2$ that appears in the question is the group cohomology of $Q$, and yours is the Cech cohomology, and the two things are quite different…)

Comment: In the description of the classifying cocycle of a central extension, no particular property of $Q$ is used. The point is with the topology on $Q$ it is natural to use continuous cocycles.

Comment: My point is that the class you are constructing is entirely useless in classifying extensions of a discretye $Q$, simply because it takes values in the cohomology of the discrete space $Q$, which has $H^2=0$. In other words, your "classifying cocycle" does not classify anything, for any example the OP is interested in,.